# GET works through postman, but returns org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException in CLI

Tags: spring, http, curl, get

Using spring I wrote a method that should return an array of json objects when GET is called. I checked through PostMan everything works, but when I try to do the GET using curl I get

```
{"timestamp":1503570488519,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/audpro/report"}
```

This is the address for postman `localhost:8080/audpro/report`

My curl command

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/audpro/report" -H "accept:application/json"
```

Why is that?

Comment: Try this : curl  "http://localhost:8080/audpro/report"  -H "content-type:application/json"

Comment: @Ajit it works without `;`

Comment: Sorry `;` was added by mistake .  `curl "localhost:8080/audpro/report" -H "content-type:application/json"`.